# Vue access property by this or vm.$data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and I'm unsure about how to access the viewmodel data. 
When do i need to use `this.property` and when do i have to use `vm.$data.property`.

In the example below i have a table where i can select rows, i have methods to select all rows and deselect all rows. In deselect i can access selectedRows by `this.selectedRows`. In select however i have to use `rowTableVm.$data.selectedRow`s because this.selectedRows is undefined.

When do i need to use this. and when do i need to use vm.$data.

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="row in get_rows()">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="row.id" v-model="selectedRows">
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

var rowTableVm = new Vue({
        el: '#rowTable',
        data: {
            rowList: [{..},{..}],
            selectedRows: []
        },
        methods: {
            get_rows: function get_rows() {
                return this.rowList;
            },
            deselect_rows: function () {
                this.selectedRows= [];
            },
            select_rowse: function () {
                this.deselect_rows();
                this.get_rows().forEach(function (entry) {
                    rowTableVm.$data.selectedRows.push(entry.id);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you run into the issue you're having is due to scoping. Specifically, `this` inside of the `forEach` is no longer bound to the Vue instance. In order to resolve this problem, try storing the reference in a variable prior to entering the loop, like in the following:

```
select_rowse: function () {
    this.deselect_rows();
    var this_vue_instance = this;
    this.get_rows().forEach(function (entry) {
        this_vue_instance.selectedRows.push(entry.id);
    });
}
```

In general, you should try to avoid using `vm.$data` whenever possible. In particular, you will run into issues if you have multiple references to the variable scattered throughout your code and if you ever need to rename the variable, whereas `this` will remain consistent. Only use a variable reference if absolutely necessary, which should be infrequent.

Comment: Just as a clartification: That has nothing to do with Vuejs, it' just how `this` works in `forEach` (and many other places) - it's something fundamental about Javascript itself.

Comment: Is it better to always reference the vm.$data? I will most likely be using a lot of forEach blocks for example.

Comment: @LordVermillion As I said, you should avoid using `vm.$data` whenever possible. Stick to using a variable reference to `this` instead. Alternatively, it looks like `Array.forEach` has a method signature that looks like `forEach(callback, thisArg)`, where `thisArg` allows you to pass in a `this` reference to use explicitly. Thus, you can do `this.get_rows().forEach(function (entry) { . . . }, this);` and that should rebind what `this` references in your `forEach` call. But absolutely avoid using `vm.$data` as it's very bad practice!